# create php table from javascript value and return it as table

Tags: javascript, php

I have this javascript return code :

```
function format(value) {
      return '<div>Detail Item : ' + value + '</div>';
  }
```

then I have other php file that proceed sql based on value in javascript function.

```
$query = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * from penjualan where id_usr = $javascriptvalue");
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

what I still confuse is how to pass that javascript named **value** to php file in variable javascriptvalue then after that pass it back again in javascript return as a table

Comment: Did you mean to use the [tag:javascript] tag and *not* the [tag:java] question tag?

Comment: OK, I'll just change them for you and let you notify me if I did wrong.

Comment: oh sorry must be misstyping when create question, thx for the edit tho

Answer (score 0):

Javascript variables are on client side and php runs on server side. To access javascript variables in php you have to send the variables to php by using POST method (or GET). You can also use AJAX to send the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
First, catch your variable 'value' on client side.

After that, you could send it to server side using jquery for example.

```
    $('#btn-form').click(function () {
        var value = '1';
        $.ajax({
            url: "file.php",
            method: 'POST',               
            data: {"value": value},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                console.log('Error: ' + errorThrown + 'textStatus: ' + textStatus + 'XMLHttpRequest: ' + XMLHttpRequest);
            }
        });
    })
```

Now, on server side, you could retrieve the value of the variable in order to use it in the sql sentence.

```
  $sValue = $_POST["value"];
```

Try not to concatenate variables in sql strings, instead, you could use  prepared statements.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php